# How to define variables when jQuery is inserted in the footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, footer

I am writing a plugin for a cms that has jQuery embedded at the end of the html document.

I do dynamically define some variables in my template code like that:

```
<script>
    var name = '<?php echo $nameTakenFromTheDatabase; ?>';
</script>
```

This code is part of my plugin and it is *not* embedded on every page. Thus, *name* is not defined on every page.

I also do have this Javascript Code in a separate file (that gets automatically added to the page end by the cms):

```
var MyNamespace = (function() {

    MyClass = function(name) {
        // Do something with name
    }

    return {
        MyClass: MyClass
    }

})();
```

If jQuery was embedded at the top, I'd do something like this in my template code:

```
<script>
    var name = '<?php echo $nameTakenFromTheDatabase; ?>';

    $(document).ready(function() {
        new MyNamespace.MyClass(name);        
    });
</script>
```

However, with jQuery included at the bottom I can't do that ($ is not defined yet). I as well can't just add the jQuery-DomReady call to the separate code file, because this is executed on every page, but the *name* var is not initalized on every pages and breaks the code.

What can I do? Is the good old document.ready a wise approach?

Comment: Based on solutions proposed and problem you described I would say that "good old document.ready" is a wise approach here. Of course if you have a more complex problem but you simplified it here then I would vote for @aaberg solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define methods in you script, and execute them from the global javascript file.

If you do something like this in you page

```
<script>
    var name = '<?php echo $nameTakenFromTheDatabase; ?>';

    function runWhenReady(){
        new MyNamespace.MyClass(name);        
    }
</script>
```

Then in you global file, which is added at the bottom of the page, you can do something like this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    if (typeof runWhenReady != 'undefined') {
        runWhenReady();
    }
});
```

If you are creative, you could make 'runWhenReady' a collection of methods, which would always be loaded when page is ready.

**EDIT I have added an example of using an array:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // check if array is already created. This is necessary if it is possible to render multiple pages which uses the runWhenReadyFunctions collection.
        if (typeof runWhenReadyFunctions == 'undefined'){
            window.runWhenReadyFunctions = new Array();
        }

        runWhenReadyFunctions.push(function(){
            $('#testDiv').text('hello world!');
        });

        runWhenReadyFunctions.push(function(){
            $('#testDiv2').text('hello another world!');
        })

    </script>


    <div id="testDiv"></div>
    <div id="testDiv2"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof runWhenReadyFunctions != 'undefined') {
            $.each(runWhenReadyFunctions, function(idx, func){
                func();
            });
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess that's how I'll do it!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - ok you should not clutter the global space, i don't understand whydon't you put your `<script>` tag below the tag where you include jQuery. Otherwise you could make an AJAX call

```
<script>


    $('document').ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('getmyname.php', function(data){
            new MyNamespace.MyClass(data.name);        
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I thought of that (MyNamespace_name) ... but I don't like the idea of putting stuff in the global scope. I'm coming from PHP and I learned the lesson ^^

Comment: @shredding yes you are right my solution is not optimal, but whydon't you put the script tag below the jQuery import?i don't understand why yopu can't do that

Comment: The CMS is Typo3 and the extension is extbase. I have a view template where PHP Variables are available. This is added whereever the view is placed in the document hiearchy. I can add pure Javascript files (which are added to the buttom), but the PHP Vars are not available there (in fact, they don't get parsed but are just delivered to the browser). I do not have access to the cms, I'm just writing the plugin.

Comment: @shredding can't you make an AJAX call and get the name by yourself? i edited my answer

Comment: No, I would have to Reboot the extbase CMS framework to do so -> big overhead. I tried your first approach but still get the "Undefined var MyNamespace_name" Exception.

Comment: Is there a reason behind why your codes does not say $(document) but $('document')?

Comment: @shreddin if you write `if(typeof MyNamespace_name !== 'undefined')` this evalueates to true?That's strange

Comment: Irks. Missed the parantheses: ''